Python Pandas str.extract with one capture group only works in some cases
I have a single column in a big datasheet which I want to change, by extracting substrings from the string in that column. I do this by using str.extract on that column like so:



Groups




Group (A)


Group (B)


Group (CA)


Group (CB)


Group (G)


Group (XP)



What I want to get is the following:



Groups




(A)


(B)


(CA)


(CB)


(G)


(XP)



I did try doing this with str.extract as mentioned above, because the datasheet is transformed into a Dataframe for more data transformation stuff beforehand. Usually this works just fine, but in this case it doesn't. The relevant code is
rule = "(\(A\)|\(B\)|\(G\)|\(CA\)|\(CB\)|\(XP\))"
df["Groups"] = df["Groups"].str.extract(rule, expand=True)

For some ungodly reason, it only extracts (A) and (B), not (G), nor any other characters.
What am I doing wrong?
Edit: The code around the whole application is super convoluted, badly maintained and overall not all that stable, so the issue may be somewhere else. But since this is the first and only case where this happened in any transformation, because it usually works fine for other cases, and since I managed to isolate it pretty well, the mistake should be within the issue described above.

For clarity, can you provide the output of df['Groups'].to_dict()?

This works fine in my hands, you have to use a raw string (r'...') to avoid the DeprecationWarning:
rule = r'(\(A\)|\(B\)|\(G\)|\(CA\)|\(CB\)|\(XP\))'
df['out'] = df['Groups'].str.extract(rule, expand=True)

Another, more generic, option could be to allow anything between the parentheses, except parentheses themselves:
rule = r'(\([^()]+\))'
df['out2'] = df['Groups'].str.extract(rule, expand=True)

Or, using a non-greedy quantifier:
rule = r'(\(.+?\))'
df['out3'] = df['Groups'].str.extract(rule, expand=True)

Output:
       Groups   out  out2  out3
0   Group (A)   (A)   (A)   (A)
1   Group (B)   (B)   (B)   (B)
2  Group (CA)  (CA)  (CA)  (CA)
3  Group (CB)  (CB)  (CB)  (CB)
4   Group (G)   (G)   (G)   (G)
5  Group (XP)  (XP)  (XP)  (XP)

Regex demos:

original regex
(\([^()]+\))
(\(.+?\))

If, really, the first approach doesn't work for you, you might have hidden characters that cause the regex to fail.

Yeah, I guess the issue is somewhere else in the code, so I'll have to keep digging. But thanks anyways, at least good to know that my understanding of regex or str.extract() wasn't the issue. <3

Check for hidden characters. Have you tested if my alternative regexes work for you?

They don't. In isolation they do, obviously, but the whole application is for converting and editing excel files, so I guess the issue lies somewhere deeper in the code. Just strange that I never ran into the problem beforehand

Thank you for answering, I found the issue. It was indeed in the code, the cases that failed to be extracted simply were ignored by the function that handles the extraction. To think that I pulled my hair out about this issue for 3 hours and the solution was that simple...
If a mod ever finds this, they can delete the question since it has no real value anymore, but until then I will keep it to remind everyone that the dumbest issues are sometimes the right ones...
